# Ansible install custom RPM's based on OS Version

Tags: ansible, rpm, yum

I need a playbook that transfer and install the following custom RPM's base on a hosts file that includes Centos 6, 7, and 8:

- package.sl6.x86_64.rpm
- package.sl7.x86_64.rpm
- package.sl8.x86_64.rpm

```
---
- hosts: centos678
  become: true

  tasks:
    ############ Copy
    - name: Copy rpm - centos 6
      copy:
        src: package.sl6.x86_64.rpm
        dest: /tmp/package.sl6.x86_64.rpm
        force: no
      when: ansible_distribution_major_version == '6'
    - name: Copy rpm - centos 7
      copy:
        src: package.sl7.x86_64.rpm
        dest: /tmp/package.sl7.x86_64.rpm
        force: no
      when: ansible_distribution_major_version == '7'
    - name: Copy rpm  - centos 8
      copy:
        src: package.sl8.x86_64.rpm
        dest: /tmp/package.sl8.x86_64.rpm
        force: no
      when: ansible_distribution_major_version == '8'

    ############ Install
    - name: Install the RPM - centos 6
      yum:
        name: /tmp/package.sl6.x86_64.rpm
        state: present
      when: ansible_distribution_major_version == '6'
    - name: Install the RPM - centos 7
      yum:
        name: /tmp/package.sl7.x86_64.rpm
        state: present
      when: ansible_distribution_major_version == '7'
    - name: Install the RPM - centos 8
      yum:
        name: /tmp/package.sl8.x86_64.rpm
        state: present
      when: ansible_distribution_major_version == '8'
```

This works, but could this be done more efficiently like only one copy task and one install task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```yaml
---
- hosts: centos678
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  vars:
    package_name: "package.sl{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.x86_64.rpm"
    package_path: "/tmp/{{ package_name }}"
  tasks:
    - name: copy rpm to required target
      copy:
        src: "{{ package_name }}"
        dest: "{{ package_path }}"

    - name: install rpm
      yum:
        name: "{{ package_path }}"
```

Comment: Indeed, just [select files variable based on facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#selecting-variables-files-based-on-facts) ...